# Dynamically remove a column from a CSV

Tags: python

I want to dynamically remove a column from a CSV, this is what I have so far. I have no idea where to go from here though:

```
# Remove column not needed.
column_numbers_to_remove = 3,2,
file = upload.filepath
#I READ THE FILE
file_read = csv.reader(file)

REMOVE 3 and 2 column from the CSV
UPDATE SAVE CSV
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to get the column index, and create a new row without the columns you don't want... eg:

```
for row in file_read:
    new_row = [col for idx, col in enumerate(row) if idx not in (3, 2)]
```

Then write out your rows using `csv.writer` somewhere...

Comment: Do I need to save the file or will this done in this process.

Comment: @user7 You will need to open a file for writing, and create a `csv.writer`, and use `.writerow()` - see http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Answer (score 1):

Read the csv and write into another file after removing the columns.

```
import csv
creader = csv.reader(open('csv.csv'))
cwriter = csv.writer(open('csv2.csv', 'w'))

for cline in creader:
   new_line = [val for col, val in enumerate(cline) if col not in (2,3)]
   cwriter.writerow(new_line)
```

Comment: remember that `csv` doesn't  close the file for you. Otherwise a good example

Comment: As an aside: the fileobj opened by csv.writer should be opened in binary mode, eg: `'wb'`

Comment: @thavan indeed - but I'll point you to the [warning in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer): `If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.` - and since it makes no difference where it's not needed - it's generally advised to use it regardless